# Browser client can't connect to DynamoDB in Docker container

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I've been using `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb` server-side (SvelteKit / NodeJS) connecting to localhost Docker container with instance of `amazon/dynamodb-local:latest` which works well. I used AWS CLI to configure tables, etc. I've created the client using the simplest configuration:

```
  const client = new DynamoDBClient({ endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000' });
```

This works server-side, but when the same is executed client-side along with a command, I get a message that the region is missing. I've tried passing `region: 'none'`, but then I get a message that the credentials are missing. Adding dummy credentials enables the command to execute, but I don't get an expected response. For example, sending the `ListTablesCommand` returns an empty array. If I do the same from the AWS CLI, I get the correct response.

Does the DynamoDB client run client-side, i.e., in the browser? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't run in a browser, You will need API Gateway and some backend code to connect a browser to Dynamodb.